# XPath expression to extract records with a defined child

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm writing a C# program to query an XML file (database of books).
I want to query all the records with a defined author: the <authors> are defined as a list of <author>.
So far I used the following:

```
itemNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//record[contains(translate( authors/author, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '" + strSearch.ToLower() + "')]");
```

It is OK with this record:

```
<record>
  <_formats>PDF</_formats>
  <publisher>Alessio Roberti Editore</publisher>
  <authors sort="Dilts, Robert">
    <author>Robert Dilts</author>
  </authors>
...
```

but it misses this one:

```
<record>
  <_formats>AZW3, EPUB</_formats>
  <publisher>Alessio Roberti Editore</publisher>
  <authors sort="Gilligan, Stephen &amp; Dilts, Robert">
    <author>Stephen Gilligan</author>
    <author>Robert Dilts</author>
  </authors>
...
```

Here the author is the second item of the list.
How can i change the expression to return both the records?

Comment: Since you are using C#, you can take Linq2Xml instead. It can be easy used to avoid the problem of single quotes in the text, ignorecase comparison, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i change the expression to return both the records?

Easy enough. Change:

```cs
"//record[contains(authors/author, '" + strSearch.ToLower() + "')]"
```

to:

```cs
"//record[authors/author[contains(., '" + strSearch.ToLower() + "')]]"
```

Predicates can be nested.

---

That being said, instead of hard-coding the alphabet and therefore limiting the characters you can search for, use C# to accommodate searching for all characters:

```cs
var strSearch = "Search";
var xpath = String.Format(
    "//record[authors/author[contains(translate(., '{0}', '{1}'), '{1}')]]", 
    strSearch.ToUpper(),
    strSearch.ToLower()
);
```

This will still break if `strSearch` contains single quotes. Be sure to strip them beforehand. This gives you (wrapped for legibility):

```
//record[authors/author[contains(
    translate(., 'SEARCH', 'search'),
    'search'
)]]
```

---

Instead of *removing* single quotes, you can handle them properly. In XPath there are no escape sequences, so you can't simply escape them somehow.

The value `O'Connor` can only be represented in a double-quoted string in XPath: `"O'Connor"` because the `'` cannot exist in a single-quoted string (and vice versa). Unfortunately this requires prior knowledge of the string contents, which you do not have.

But you can construct an XPath expression that *evaluates* to `O'Connor`, like this: `concat('O', "'", 'Connor')`. This kind of expression can be constructed automatically from any input, no matter how many single quotes it contains:

```
string escapeXPath(string input) {
    if (input.Contains("'"))
        return "concat('" + String.Join("', \"'\", '", input.Split('\'')) + "')";
    return "'" + input + "'";
}
```

so you can incorporate it like this (there's a subtle difference to the above w/r/t single quotes):

```cs
var strSearch = "O'Connor";
var xpath = String.Format(
    "//record[authors/author[contains(translate(., {0}, {1}), {1})]]", 
    escapeXPath(strSearch.ToUpper()),
    escapeXPath(strSearch.ToLower())
);
```

which gives you the safe XPath 1.0 expression (wrapped for legibility):

```
//record[authors/author[contains(
    translate(., concat('O', "'", 'CONNOR'), concat('o', "'", 'connor')), 
    concat('o', "'", 'connor')
)]]
```

without sacrificing the ability to search for single quotes (or characters outside of the A-Z range).

Comment: Thanks, but the program crashes saying that *System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: contains takes 2 args*

Comment: @SteMMo Using `String.Format()` results in nicer code. Updated again.